# How to send message proactively to Skype user through botframework output channel using Rasa

Tags: botframework, skype, rasa

I am struggling with a problem that I have to integrate sending message to **Skype** users in daily. I've tried using API (https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/pages/http-api#operation/executeConversationAction) to run action and trigger intent  but it didn't work. I think the problem here is **botframework** is not supported output channel because it worked on **Telegram**.

This is the result when output channel is **botframework** but it doesn't appear when I set it by **telegram**

How can I do this task? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the botframework channel is not supported because it doesn't implement a [`get_output_channel`](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/dbe31e5736f4d767e92e08b348a67975c29ae115/rasa/core/channels/channel.py#L130-L142) method, which is used for the intent injection.

However, I'm not sure why that is the case, as I'm not familiar with the channel. It would be dependent on the type of communication connection, i.e. if in botframework Rasa is able to send messages to the channel without having received one first. In the channel code, sending a message looks like a POST request, so I would assume that is the case.

I think you could open an enhancement request in the Rasa repo for this.